# Jmeter can't be installed in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, installation, jmeter

please can you have a look around of what i've been missing to install my Jmeter 5.5 at Ubuntu locally.   Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

please find below:

```
root@luisr-A10N-8800E:/home/luisr# cd Descargas/apache-jmeter-5.5/bin/
root@luisr-A10N-8800E:/home/luisr/Descargas/apache-jmeter-5.5/bin# ./jmeter
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2398)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:785)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1979)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:395)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:234)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:322)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:289)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2403)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:848)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2015)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1392)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1390)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.initStatic(Toolkit.java:1427)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:625)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon$2.run(ImageIcon.java:145)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon$2.run(ImageIcon.java:143)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.createNoPermsComponent(ImageIcon.java:142)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon$1.run(ImageIcon.java:114)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon$1.run(ImageIcon.java:111)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<clinit>(ImageIcon.java:111)
    at org.apache.jmeter.plugin.PluginManager.installPlugin(PluginManager.java:61)
    at org.apache.jmeter.plugin.PluginManager.install(PluginManager.java:47)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:464)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)
An error occurred: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
```

i have tried nothing else yet to solve this issue.  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have [headless JDK](https://packages.debian.org/sid/openjdk-11-jdk-headless) installed which doesn't allow to run GUI programs.

You should be able to [run JMeter in non-GUI mode though](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
./jmeter -n -t ../extras/Test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

If you plan to run JMeter GUI you will need to install [**full** version of JDK](https://packages.debian.org/sid/openjdk-11-jdk):

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```